# ffmpeg text relocations issues on

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have been working on a little app that use [FFMPEG Android library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)  in order to convert some videos files. However, the app is crashing on any devices >= 23. I read that this can be fixed either by downgrading your SDK to 22 or using `--disable-asm` (make it very slow). I want to test the second case but I could not find a good documentation how to implement it on Android. Here my cmd:

```
String cmd="--disable-asm -i " + videoName + "-i watermark.jpg -filter_complex " + overlay + " -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy " +"repostvideo.mp4";
```

Unfortunately this is not working. So my question how or where would I put `--disable-asm` in my cmd in order to make it work?

Thanks.

Edit 1: Logcat errors

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/xxxx": "/data/data/xxxx" has text relocations.

Version:

> implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

Comment: Kindly Add Crash log. Also which version of FFMPEG library are you using ?

Comment: @Nakul I just included them...

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue from **WritingMinds**. 
Check it [here](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/141)

I haven't tried it myself, but try using the following ffmpeg library version; it claims to have solved this issue.

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android

**Edit**

Check the repository's about section, it specifically says

> This project is a continued fork of FFmpeg Android Java by WritingMinds. This fork fixes the CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE ffmpeg: has text relocations issue on x86 devices along with some other bugfixes, new features and the newest FFmpeg builds.

Only possible solution I think is changing library. Please understand there is no code associated with this approach.
And I can only attach link of the repo.

Fix from WritingMinds is pending I think.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20779678)

Comment: @NeilPatrao I understand the risk. But I proposed solution to change the library. I have improved the description.