# FFmpegAndroid CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, trim

I used  this library   implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'.
But i get an error.CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/com.example.newapplication/files/ffmpeg": "/data/data/com.example.newapplication/files/ffmpeg" has text relocations (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Text-Relocations-Enforced-for-API-level-23)
is there anyone who know reason?

this is code and i just want to trim(cut) video in time range i want. others is not necessary

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String outPutFile;
Uri filePath, filePathSecond, photoUri, AudioUri;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 110;
private int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO_2 = 115;
private int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_PHOTO = 120;
private int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_AUDIO = 130;
private FFmpeg ffmpeg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);


    }
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    findViewById(R.id.selectVideo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.start).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null) {
                executeCutVideoCommand(1000, 4 * 1000, filePath);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.background).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null && photoUri != null) {
                executeBackgroundCommand(filePath, photoUri);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.selectPhoto).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_PHOTO);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.speed).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null) {
                executeSpeedCommand(.9f, filePath);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.rotate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null) {
                executeRotateCommand(3, filePath);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.selectAudio).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_AUDIO);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.setAudio).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null && AudioUri != null) {
                executeChangeMusicCommand(filePath, AudioUri);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.mute).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null) {
                executeMuteCommand(filePath);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.volume).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null) {
                executeVolumeCommand(filePath, .5f);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.audio_trim).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (AudioUri != null) {
                executeCutAudioCommand(1 * 1000, 10 * 1000, AudioUri);
            }
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.marge_video).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null && filePathSecond != null)
                executeMargeVideoCommand(filePath, filePathSecond);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.selectVideo_2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO_2);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.ratio_video).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (filePath != null)
                executeRatioCommand(filePath, 2, 5);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.filter_video).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(filePath!=null){
                executeFilterCommand(filePath);
            }
        }
    });
    loadFFMpegBinary();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            filePath = uri;
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO_2) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            filePathSecond = uri;
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_PHOTO) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            photoUri = uri;
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_AUDIO) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            AudioUri = uri;
        }
    }
}

private void executeBackgroundCommand(Uri filePath, Uri photoUri) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "set_background_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    String yourRealPathImage = getPath(MainActivity.this, photoUri);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }
   /* Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: startMs: " + startMs);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: endMs: " + endMs);*/
    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    //String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};
    String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPathImage, "-i", yourRealPath
            , "-filter_complex", "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2", outPutFile};
    //   String[] complexCommand = {"-i", "" + yourRealPath, "-i", "" +yourRealPathImage, "-filter_complex", "overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10",outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

// video trim
private void executeCutVideoCommand(int startMs, int endMs, Uri filePath) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "cut_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }
   /* Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: startMs: " + startMs);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: endMs: " + endMs);*/
    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    //String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};
    String[] complexCommand = {"-ss",
            "" + (startMs / 1000),
            "-y",
            "-i",
            yourRealPath,
            "-t",
            "" + ((endMs - startMs) / 1000),
            "-vcodec",
            "mpeg4",
            "-b:v",
            "2097152",
            "-b:a",
            "48000",
            "-ac",
            "2",
            "-ar",
            "22050",
            outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                             String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

private void loadFFMpegBinary() {
    try {
        if (ffmpeg == null) {
            ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
        }
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    progressDialog.show();
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {


                System.out.println("ssss"+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                //    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SUCCESS" + outPutFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // do nothing for now
    }
}

private void executeSpeedCommand(float speed, Uri filePath) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "speed_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]setpts=" + (2.5 - speed) + "*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=" + speed + "[a]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", "-b:v", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}


private void executeRotateCommand(int rotate, Uri filePath) {

    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "speed_rotation_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] complexCommand = null;
    if (rotate == 3) {
        complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", yourRealPath, "-filter:v", "transpose=2,transpose=2", outPutFile};

    } else {
        complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", yourRealPath, "-filter:v", "transpose=" + rotate, outPutFile};
    }
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void executeChangeMusicCommand(Uri filePath, Uri audioUri) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "audio_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    String yourRealPathAudio = getPath(MainActivity.this, audioUri);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-i", yourRealPathAudio, "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-shortest", outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void executeMuteCommand(Uri filePath) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "mute_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-vcodec", "copy", "-an", outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void executeVolumeCommand(Uri filePath, float volume) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "volume_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-filter:a", "volume=" + volume, outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void executeCutAudioCommand(int startMs, int endMs, Uri filePath) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "cut_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp3";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }
   /* Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: startMs: " + startMs);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: endMs: " + endMs);*/
    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    //String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};
    String[] complexCommand = {"-ss",
            "" + (startMs / 1000),
            "-y",
            "-i",
            yourRealPath,
            "-t",
            "" + ((endMs - startMs) / 1000),
            "-vcodec",
            "mpeg4",
            "-b:v",
            "2097152",
            "-b:a",
            "48000",
            "-ac",
            "2",
            "-ar",
            "22050",
            outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void executeMargeVideoCommand(Uri filePath, Uri filePathSecond) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "marge_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    String yourRealPath2 = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePathSecond);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    String complexCommand[] = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-i", yourRealPath2, "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]scale=iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v] scale=iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
            "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "1920x1080", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "27",
            "-q", "4", "-preset", "ultrafast", outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void executeRatioCommand(Uri filePath, int w, int h) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "ratio_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    //  String complexCommand[] = {"-i", yourRealPath,"-r", "15", "-aspect" ,""+w+":"+""+h ,"-strict" ,"-2",outPutFile};
    String complexCommand[] = new String[]{"-i", yourRealPath, "-lavf", "[0:v]scale=1920*2:1080*2,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=-1:1080[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=w=1920:h=1080", outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}


private void executeFilterCommand(Uri filePath) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );
    String filePrefix = "filter_change_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, filePath);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    outPutFile = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    //  String complexCommand[] = {"-i", yourRealPath,"-r", "15", "-aspect" ,""+w+":"+""+h ,"-strict" ,"-2",outPutFile};
    String complexCommand[] = { "-i",yourRealPath,"-vf", "split [main][tmp]; [tmp] lutyuv=","y=val*5"," [tmp2]; [main][tmp2] overlay", outPutFile};
    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}

}
```

Comment: See similar questions: [FFMPEG progress CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE … ffmpeg: has text relocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400074/ffmpeg-progress-cannot-link-executable-ffmpeg-has-text-relocations) and [ffmpeg text relocations issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182073/ffmpeg-text-relocations-issues-on)